# What does mean an electronic symbol of operational amplifier, but with only one input?

Tags: electronics

What does mean a symbol of operational amplifier with only one input ?

See for example :
http://physicsopenlab.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/CSP.png

Does this means that the + input of the operational amplifier is connected to ground ?

Does it mean that the + and the - inputs of the operational amplifier are connected together ?

Is it in order to save space in the figure ?

Comment: It is a [buffer amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_amplifier).

Comment: Thank you Farcher. I have looked at the link you sent. Does it mean that the - input of the operational amplifier is connected to the output, or is it the + input that is connected ? Anyway, this web page describes the voltage follower, without capacity in parallel, so I'm not completely sure that it is directly connected to the symbol that I showed.